# Maximum number of disks to attach to Dev virtual machines in Deployment settings

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365-operations, d3fo

What is the meaning of this number? How do I know how many disks I need for a developer box?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> How do I know how many disks I need for a developer box?

I was searching for an official answer to this a couple of weeks ago, but couldn't find anything specific about that in the official documentation.

However, I found [this](https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/b/365foroperationstechnical/archive/2019/02/12/speed-up-your-development-environment) community entry, which contains a lot of helpful information regarding that topic.

> What is the meaning of this number?

The number itself describes how many data disks your Virtual Machine will actually have attached in Azure. You can then configure each of these individually.

I personally use 2 data disks with 256Gb each for development which works well, but less would also be enough.
The data disk configuration for that setup looks like this in Azure: 
[image]

The OS disk and build disk are both fixed.